# vkbeautify module not defined angular 8.2.14

Tags: angular

I have an inherited error from a angular 8 app. I am not sure why this is happening. I have all of the code placed correctly yet the error remains. I have included the vkbeautify in my app.module.ts in declaration, exports and based on the documentation everything needed to get this error to go away. The plugin works and is working fine but this error is not going anywhere. WHat am I doing wrong here?

XMLPipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as vkbeautify from 'vkbeautify';

@Pipe({
  name: 'xml'
})
export class XmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, args?: any): string {
    return vkbeautify.xml(value);
  }

}
```

Shared.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule, NgbDateAdapter, NgbDateNativeAdapter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { FieldLabelComponent } from './fieldlabel.component';
import { FieldInputComponent } from './fieldinput.component';
import { FieldDisplayComponent } from './fielddisplay.component';
import { XmlPipe } from './xml.pipe';
import { NbspPipe } from './nbsp.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        FieldLabelComponent,
        FieldInputComponent,
        FieldDisplayComponent,
        XmlPipe,
        NbspPipe
    ],
    exports: [
        FieldLabelComponent,
        FieldInputComponent,
        FieldDisplayComponent,
        XmlPipe,
        NbspPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}
     ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

angular.json:

```
"projects": {
    "E-Toolbox": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/E-Toolbox/",
            "outputPath": "../../wwwroots/E-ClosingSecured/E-Toolbox/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/vkbeautify/index.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
```

ERROR in console:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    module.exports=new vkbeautify;
```

Comment: I can add any info or code needed. I am also willing to jump on a call if possible?

Comment: I have been searching around and made several edits to my tsconfig.json but nothing worked to resolve the error. I just added this line to my index.html in the head and the error is gone and everything still works. But WHY>>>?
```<script>var module = {};</script> ```